Understanding ファンの数だけあって良い
There is one sentence I don't understand from the recent chapter of Oshi no ko:

アイドルのどこを推すのかもどうして推すのかもどうやって推すかもファンの数だけあって良い

How the last part ファンの数だけあって良い is understood? I think ファンの数だけ means ファンの数分だけ. I believe the whole sentence means "it is alright for questions like where to support an idol, why support an idol, how to support an idol, to exist, as much as the number of fans for that idol."

You're close, but "どこを推すのか", "どうして推すのか" and "どうやって推すか" are not genuine "questions" in this context.

どこを推すのか: aspects to appreciate (e.g., dance, visuals, talking skills, singing, ...)
どうして推すのか: the reasons for supporting
どうやって推すか: the ways of supporting

The sentence is saying it's alright that there can be as many of these elements as there are fans.

Thank you but I don't get how they can't be treated as questions even though they end with か.

@JohnDavies I mean, using an embedded question such as "when he speaks" or "what I do" does not necessarily mean you are "asking a question", right? "What I do" usually just means "the thing I do".
